# Where is the save directory for screenshot?

Tags: screenshot

I was wondering what is the default saving directory for *Accessories > Take Screenshot*?

I just took a screenshot and I am looking for where it is saved.

Comment: If you're asking this question, it's probably because gnome-screenshot crashed after/while taking the screenshot. (To confirm, launch it in a terminal with `gnome-screenshot -i`, and look for "segmentation fault" when it crashes.) In the normal course of things (if it doesn't crash), it should ask you for a directory where to save the file, immediately after taking the screenshot.

Comment: If you're wondering about `Ctrl` + `PrtSc` too, and not just `PrtSc`, see [my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1389947/327339).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be the desktop directory: `~/Desktop`.

You can change it before pressing "Save" button.

Comment: unless otherwise specified in its options.

Comment: Thanks！ But there is no option for me to specify its directory, and it is not my Desktop by default. Once I hit the take Screenshot button, the application has no more question to ask me.

Comment: @Tim: I think it crashes: launch it in a terminal with `gnome-screenshot -i`

Comment: On Ubuntu 17.10, pressing `Shift` + `Print `, and then selecting a custom rectangular area, saves the screenshot inside `~/Pictures/`

Answer (score 18):

**For 18.04: `~/Pictures`**

From: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-take-a-screenshot-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

> screenshot is a default application for taking screenshots on Gnome
> desktop. To take screenshot simply hit PrtSc button on your keyboard
> and the screenshot of your entire desktop will be taken and saved as
> *.png file inside your ~/Pictures directory.

Comment: 2 Notes: 1) You must first hit save on the dialog window, otherwise it won't save ! x)  2) If you have localized version of Ubuntu, it will be in your home translation of Pictures `~/PicturesInYourLanguage`

Answer (score 6):

On my keyboard, Microsoft Wireless Natural Multimedia Keyboard, if I use the right <kbd>Shift</kbd> key along with the <kbd>Print</kbd> key, I am able to select screenshot area and save the image to a location. 
If I use the left <kbd>Shift</kbd> key along with <kbd>Print</kbd> key, i am able to select `print area` but it copies the image to the clipboard.  Side note, I don't believe Left <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Print</kbd> does anything different than Left <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Print</kbd>, both give you a cross hair and copy to clipboard.

Answer (score 2):

After you took your screenshot (e.g. by pressing <kbd>Print</kbd> or selecting *Take Screenshot* from the applications menu/Dash) you have a selection of  where you want to save the image. You can either *Copy to Clipboard* or yo ucan save it to a specified directory. By clicking on the dropdown menu next to *Save in folder:* you can change the save directory easily:

[image]

By selecting *Other...* we may enter any directory of our choice. This selection will be remembered for the next time (saved in *gconf*: `/apps/gnome-screenshot/last_save_directory`).

Comment: this option is **not** saved by default, as for 14.10.

Comment: @EliranMalka: It only works in `gnome-screenshot --interactive`. This probably is [bug #977228](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screenshot/+bug/977228) - defininitely not how it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

Screenshots are not saved automatically; you have to save them yourself. The default screenshot directory is either the desktop or the home folder, and is named Screenshot#.png

Comment: This answer is obsolete, Please look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**11.04 and up**

You can take screenshots simply by pressing the <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> key. A window will pop-up asking for the name and directory to save the screenshot to or if you wish to copy it to the clipboard.

[image]

You can also narrow your screenshot to just the active window by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>PrtScr</kbd> instead.

Answer (score 0):

By default Ubuntu keeps screenshot at the pictures folder. Anyways it provides option to change the destination as per user. Please visit the Pictures folder

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu `18.04` Just press <kbd>PrtSc</kbd>.

I was using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Print</kbd>, OR <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Print</kbd>, it was taking the screenshot in the clipboard but wasn't storing the screenshot in the `/home/{user}/Pictures` directory.

Answer (score 0):

*For Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04+:*

I want to add that:

1. **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PrtSc</kbd>** (PrintScreen) will take a screenshot and *copy it to the **clipboard***. It does NOT save the image anywhere on your file system. Paste the screenshot into another program, such as LibreOffice Writer, with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.
2. **Just <kbd>PrtSc</kbd>** will take a screenshot and *save it on your file system inside the `~/Pictures` directory* in the format `Screenshot from YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS.png`. Ex: `~/Pictures/Screenshot from 2022-01-29 09-03-13.png`.

   1. Note: depending on your keyboard, you may have to use the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key or other keys as well to activate the <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> key.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> – Captures a Screenshot of the entire screen as it is. This is then saved to the ‘Pictures’ directory.
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> – Captures a screenshot of a specific region that you select. This is also saved to the ‘Pictures’ directory.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> – Captures a screenshot of the current window you are working on. This is also saved to the ‘Pictures’ directory.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> – This shortcut copies the screenshot of the entire screen directly to the clipboard.
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> – This shortcut copies the screenshot of a specific region that you select on the clipboard.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> – This shortcut copies the screenshot of the current window that you are working on to the clipboard.