# How can I specify the default save directory for gnome-screenshot?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, gnome-screenshot, print-screen

Are there any sort of configuration options for specifying the default save location for `gnome-screenshot`, or is this hard-coded into the source code?

It used to be `~/Desktop`, which seems to have changed to `~/Pictures` (in 12.04).

The only possible solution I've seen is about [Setting the default name](https://askubuntu.com/a/55235/50523) (as it includes time stamp information now instead of simply 'Screenshot#'), but that solution doesn't really seem ideal to me.

Also, [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/52204/50523) post suggested that the last save location is remembered the next time you take a screenshot, but in my experience, this doesn't seem to be the case. And in any case, following on from that, that entry in `gconf-editor` doesn't even seem to accurately reflect the last location, so more than likely an entry related to an older version of `gnome-screenshot`.

### Table of contents:

- [**For Ubuntu 21.10**](https://askubuntu.com/a/1373558/)
- [**For Ubuntu 18.04 +**](https://askubuntu.com/a/1102530/)
- [**For Ubuntu 17.10 +**](https://askubuntu.com/a/961149/)
- [**For Ubuntu 12.04**](https://askubuntu.com/a/134469/)

Comment: I have opened a bug report as even though the folder is recorded it is not being used to preselect it. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screenshot/+bug/1000534

Comment: The problem for me was: I had the default folder set to ~/screenshots and it was working fine for a long time. Today I noticed that it was redirecting to a folder *within* that folder and couldn't be reset. It was actually an empty subfolder in this case. I deleted the subfolder and since then it has worked fine.

Comment: Graphical methods below work, but what you *really* want to do is: `gsettings set "org.gnome.gnome-screenshot" "auto-save-directory" "file:///home/$USER/screenshot"`

Comment: If you are looking to change this using Gnome 3.8 or later, you are out of luck. [The developers have decided to remove the ability to configure this.](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=699642)

Comment: @palswim GNOME seems to be more and more going the Windows 10 path - removing configurability for many things and forcing fixed solutions on users, "knowing better than users" what they want... :(

Comment: I find it incredible that for this obvious configuration tweak, the recommended approach since 18.04 is to install an unofficial gnome shell extension (which all by itself is a *security issue*), via your *browser* (one of the hardest-to-secure parts of the whole system), and in fact via a browser *extension*, plus a *native host connector* tool. And that if you want to do it from the command line, you're pointed at example shell commands that need to be modified for each extension. What has system administration come to?? All your base are belong to whoever....

Answer (score 155, accepted):

### For 12.04

#### Via GUI

1. Install [dconf-editor](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/dconf-tools)

- From the command line, run the command `sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`
- Or click here to install from the Ubuntu Software Center:

  [image: Install via the software center]

2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type `dconf-editor`
3. Go to `org` -> `gnome` -> `gnome-screenshot`
4. At "auto-save-directory" type the desired directory in the following format: `file:///home/user/Desktop/`

   [image: name: auto-save-directory, value: file:///full/path/]

A tip for anyone who is using the configuration editor in unity: click on the arrow to the left the `org` text to expand it.

### Via Terminal

Simply run this command, replacing the path with your preferred directory.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-screenshot auto-save-directory "file:///home/$USER/Downloads/"
```

Comment: For what it's worth, this worked in Debian Wheezy for me.

Comment: Thanks desgua, this gave me less stress than changing it every time.

Comment: NB It is *auto-save-directory* as mentioned in the text, not *last-save-directory* as highlighted on the screenshot

Comment: @rds Well pointed. Updated.

Comment: Warning: using `~` in the path does not work, e.g. `~/Desktop` and `file:///~/Desktop` fail silently (picture ends up in `~`).

Comment: I have tried before and after using dconf-editor to set the auto-save directory, and my screenshots are not saved. I did a search on my home directory by modification date and there are no new files. Ubuntu 13.10. Any ideas?

Comment: Which directory exactly have you choose (file:///home...)?

Comment: it works without using `files://` in ubuntu 14.04. `Clrl+L` will tell you the location . '/home/userName/location'

Comment: I like to have a subdirectory inside Pictures called screenshots; and it's a lot more handy to have that as default.
I don't understand yet why the actual app does not provide the way to change this.

Comment: Be aware that Gnome 3.8 doesn't use gnome-screenshot when using keyboard commands.

Comment: Not `files://` but `file://`

Comment: Terminal method should be listed first since it's simpler.

Comment: Still works for Mint 18.1.

Comment: I did through terminal and now my screenshot tool does not work anymore. 

`(process:16744): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._g_2dfile_2derror_2dquark.Code24: Failed to write file '/udd/MYUSER/.config/dconf/user.DFXC6Y': fsync() failed: Disk quota exceeded` 

I got this error and then when I save the screenshot I am not able to open the picture

Comment: Now if I go in the GUI and I try to change the auto-save folder it does not allow me to do it. I enter the path but when I press ENTER it goes to the old value. Basically I was able to change it. Then I realized that it was not working and now I am not able to change it back.

Comment: @minidiable check this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/728863/cant-change-gedit-preferences-and-terminal-preferences-dont-save and this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67890/disk-quota-exceeded-problem

Comment: The Terminal gsettings method does not work on Ubuntu 18.04. There was no error or warning and screenshot still went to the default ~/Pictures/. dconf-edit doesn't work either! The auto-save-directory showed ~/Downloads/ but was ignored. All screenshots went to ~/Pictures/

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 - Using `$USER` does not work. Works with a fixed path, like:
`gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-screenshot auto-save-directory '/home/jgr/ScreenShots'`

Comment: @estibordo your solution still does not work for me on 18.04.2. tried single and double quotes. when i do GET, i can see it is set. same way as with var $USER ... :(

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screenshot/+bug/977228 reported 2012-04-09

Comment: @SYK This answer is not adequate anymore for Ubuntu 18.04. See the others answers below (useful answers now contain headers to clarify the scope of the answers).

Answer (score 37):

### For 18.04 and later

For those who wondering why is it still not working, this bug is considered as `RESOLVED WONTFIX`, [here's the sauce](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=699642).

For the workaround, you can install [an extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1179/screenshot-locations/) for this. Just turn on the switch, and go to your **Tweak Tool**, head over the **Extensions** tab, and find **Screenshot locations**.

[image: Tweak tool screenshot SS]

Click over the gear icon, and place your desired place to save, prefixed with `file://` as it's protocol to save.

[image: Settings SS]

This works too with symbolic link.

Comment: Works for me on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (bionic)

Comment: It worked for me on ubuntu 18.04.5

Comment: Works great on `20.04`!

Comment: Still works for me on 18.04.

Comment: This is not working on 21.10.  In fact, when installing the extension I do not even see it in Tweaks.

Comment: For 21.10 one only modify the folder directly from the Gnome extension (in browser) as the Extensions tab does not appear in Tweaks.  See: https://askubuntu.com/a/1373558/ for details.

Comment: sudo apt install gnome-tweaks

Answer (score 33):

### For 17.10 and later

Turns out it's not so straightforward while **capturing a screenshot with the <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> key** in **GNOME version 3.8 or later**.

First you may try to set `~/Desktop` (for example) as the autosave directory for `gnome-screenshot` following the steps below.

1. Open **dconf Editor**.
2. Navigate to `/org/gnome/gnome-screenshot/auto-save-directory`.
3. Disable *Use default value*.
4. Put `file:///home/YOUR_USERNAME/Desktop` in the *Custom value* box.

Alternatively, you may just run the following command in Terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-screenshot auto-save-directory 'file:///home/YOUR_USERNAME/Desktop'
```

But even after doing this if you press <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd>, captured screenshots will be saved in `~\Pictures` on GNOME 3.8 or later (see [this bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=699642)).
So as a workaround you may now add another custom keyboard shortcut for `gnome-screenshot` which will save captured screenshots to `~/Desktop`. To do that follow the steps.

1. Open **Settings > Keyboard** and scroll down to the bottom.
2. Click on the **+** symbol. A box should pop up.
3. Enter any name you like in the *Name* box.
4. Enter `gnome-screenshot` in the *Command* box.
5. Click on the **Set Shortcut...** button and set any keyboard combination which doesn't cause any conflict, for example <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd>.

Then logout and login again. Now <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> should save the captured screenshot in `~/Desktop`.

**P.S.** For convenience you may first change the shortcut for "*Save a screenshot to Pictures*" to something else like <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> or disable it completely and then assign <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> to the custom shortcut you just created.

---

You can refine what type of screenshot you want by using following flags  in the *command* box (`gnome-screenshot <FLAGS>`):

- `-a` (for 'area') will let you select the area to take the screenshot of using your mouse;
- `-w` (for 'window') will take a screenshot of the currently active window only (and not the whole screen);

  - `-b` will include window's border in the screenshot,
  - `-B` will not include the border,
- `-p` (for 'pointer') will include the mouse pointer in the screenshot (won't have any effect with `-a` obviously);
- `-i` (for 'interactive') will let you set the options in a poping-up dialog.

You can combine flags together: e.g., `gnome-screenshot -wB` will take a screenshot of currently active window without its border.

You can get the exhaustive list of available options/flags via `man gnome-screenshot`.

Comment: +1 because I was looking for a fix. Although this is not a fix and possibly the only workaround because after checking the bug report, the gnome team does NOT want to fix this (Which it was fine in previous versions). I also did everything you mentioned so I will be either be doing your suggestion that works or moving to KDE (At least they offer options).

Comment: If you want to emulate the "area screenshot" (where you draw a selection on your screen with your mouse), you should enter `gnome-screenshot -a` in the *command* box. As detailed in `man gnome-screenshot`, you can replace (or add to) `-a` with: `-c` to copy the image in clipboard (so you can Ctrl+V it), instead of a file; `-w` if you want to copy the current window; etc.

Comment: Another related bug report: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-settings-daemon/issues/323

Comment: Also note, as mentioned in @doug 's answer, that -i / --interactive will also use the last directory, which can be useful when you don't want to change the default save directory for every new activity, but a given activity always uses the same directory.

Answer (score 18):

### For 12.04

It can be be configured in 12.04 for 'auto save' & when using gnome-screenshot itself, `gnome-screenshot --interactive`, where the last save directory is used

What does seem to always default to Pictures is from the keyboard bindings (bug or intended?

Earlier in 12.04 the screens from the keyboard bindings used `auto-save`, people complained & it was returned to `interactive`

Both settings for `gnome-screenshot` are in gsettings & `dconf-editor`

[image]

Comment: Oh right. It does use that last save directory setting when using interactive, but introduces an additional dialog for what you want to grab - I guess this is the best I'll get. Thanks :-)

Comment: How do you set the called argument ` --interactive` when pressing CTRL Print?

Comment: @rubo77 (works on Ubuntu 20.04) Personally I just defined  a custom Keyboard shortcut "Take screenshot to last directory" that runs "gnome-screenshot --interactive". There "Grab the whole screen" should be selected by default (which should replace your <keyboard>Ctrl</keyboard>), but you still need to press Enter to confirm options. Then you'll have the usual popup with last directory selected. Not sure why we cannot have the last directory selected without the whole options selection part...

Answer (score 15):

### For 18.04 and later

First disable the default screenshot shortcut from settings:

[image: Disable default screenshot shortcut]

Create a custom keyboard shortcut in the settings:

Name it gnome-screenshot, put the command as gnome-screenshot as well

Shortcut value : enter the key [Print Screen]

Create a custom shortcut:

[image: Create a custom shortcut]

Now enter into `dconf-editor` (Install it if you do not have it yet).
Go to: org → gnome → gnome-screenshot → auto-save-directory: Change the auto save directory's custom value to the one you want.

Enter the custom path:

[image: Enter the custom path]

Comment: what is the name and command for `Save a screenshot of an Area to Pictures`. I repeated your answer with `Shift+Print` but it saves the full-screen screenshot instead of prompting for area.

Comment: got it `gnome-screenshot -a`

Answer (score 5):

### For 18.04 and later

Install the GNOME Shell extension [**Screenshot Locations**](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1179/screenshot-locations/) by [TimurKiyivinski](https://extensions.gnome.org/accounts/profile/TimurKiyivinski). Kudos to him for packaging the changes that the GNOME-team developers didn't want to implement into an extension and thus making it really simple to work around the issue.

EDIT: You still need to change the default path using dconf editor, obviously.

Answer (score 3):

### For 21.10 and later

I tried the answer labelled as "For 18.04 and later".  However,  it did not work in my 21.10 installation.  Luckily, after some trial and error, I found a workaround which is a simple modification to that one.

The basic workaround is *not* to use the **Tweak tool** as the **Extensions** does not seem to show.  Instead, install the [Screenshot Locations extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1179/screenshot-locations/) then go to your Gnome [Installed Extensions page](https://extensions.gnome.org/local/) and then click on the configuration button for the Screenshot location extension and select the folder you want and voilà.

Here is a screenshot of the configuration window: [image: screenshot of configuration window]

Answer (score 2):

In 12.04 (haven't looked in previous versions of Ubuntu because I never faced this problem) you have to set the **auto-save-directory**-setting to the desired location where you want your screenshots to be stored. By doing so every time you take screenshot it will automatically land there. I also prefer to use ~/Desktop and you are also not prompted to specify a destination like before. The only thing that indicates that you have taken a screenshot is a short flash of the screen. However I would love to know how to get the prompt back because I sometimes like to store screenshots in other folders than the default one and it would be overkill to either change the settings or move the image every time.

Comment: Where are you setting the *auto-save-directory* ?

Comment: Look at @doug's comment above my answer. In the picture of the configuration editor in the section of gnome-screenshot the first setting is auto-save-directory. Just write there the location of the desired folder (Desktop for example) and you're ready to go. :) In his example it is set to "Documents".

Answer (score 2):

### For Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander)

- Install `dconf-editor`
- Open it and go to: org → gnome → gnome-screenshot
- At `auto-save-directory` type the desired directory in the following format: `/home/user/Desktop/`

P.S.: Do not put in this format `file:///...`

Comment: Why is the "file:///..." format unacceptable? Just curious, I prefer the /home/user version better anyway.

Comment: the `file:///` format seems to work fine for me

Answer (score 2):

Because the default screenshot application always stores the screenshots below `$HOME/Pictures` and there is no apparent way to reconfigure that directory I wrote a combination of `systemd` *user* units to monitor the directory `$HOME/Pictures`. Whenever something in that directory changes, all files named `$HOME/Pictures/"Screenshot from"*` are moved to the subdirectory `$HOME/Pictures/Screenshots`.

#### Here is what I did:

Create a file `/etc/systemd/user/screenshot-mover.path`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Screenshot Watcher
Documentation=man:systemd.path
AssertPathIsDirectory=%h/Pictures
AssertPathIsDirectory=%h/Pictures/Screenshots

[Path]
PathChanged=%h/Pictures

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Create a file `/etc/systemd/user/screenshot-mover.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Screenshot Mover
Documentation=man:systemd.service
AssertPathIsDirectory=%h/Pictures
AssertPathIsDirectory=%h/Pictures/Screenshots
ConditionPathExistsGlob=%h/Pictures/Screenshot\ from*

[Service]
Type=oneshot
WorkingDirectory=%h/Pictures
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/bin/mv -v -t Screenshots "Screenshot from"*'
```

Then, for every user who wants this mechanism, issue:

```
systemctl --user daemon-reload
systemctl --user enable --now screenshot-mover.path
```

Do *not* run these commands as root, but as *your* user.

#### What it does:

Whenever something in the path `$HOME/Pictures` changes, the unit `screenshot-mover.service` gets called and moves every file that matches `$HOME/Pictures/"Screenshot from"*` to the subdirectory `$HOME/Pictures/Screenshots`. I know it is a *hack* but this approach works for me since months and I just wanted to share it.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is rather addition to [pomsky](https://askubuntu.com/users/480481/pomsky)'s [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/961149/703349).

On Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver it is possible to use <kbd>AltGr</kbd> to change some default behaviour. For example, my current settings have:

1. <kbd>Print</kbd> for `gnome-screenshot command`
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Print</kbd> for `gnome-screenshot -a`
3. <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Print</kbd> for `gnome-screenshot -wB` (no chance to redefine <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Print</kbd>)

To set those I used <kbd>AltGr</kbd> in addition to shortcuts themselves. (Thanks for asking [RichieHH](https://askubuntu.com/users/232407/richiehh))

[image: Custom shortcuts in keyboard settings]

Additionally, default commands become disabled.

[image: Screenshot section in keyboard settings]

*And a little note.* Obviously, there is no sense to change shortcuts for copying screenshots to clipboard.

Comment: What has AltGr got to do with anything in your answer?

Comment: @RichieHH to set those shortcuts you I had to press AltGr as well (in addition to shortcut itself) to avoid making screenshots.

Comment: @RichieHH Added to my original answer as well. Thanks

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer, but perhaps it should explain a bit better, that you have to keep pressing AltGr and then your desired combination, in order to replace the desired combination if it has been taken already, and that's how you can also replace the printscreen.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1102530/279745)

As I wanted to use custom shortcuts in addition to custom screenshots location, I wanted to do this manually in terminal.

(1) I have created [`gshort`](https://gitlab.com/tukusejssirs/lnx_scripts/blob/master/bash_functions/gshort.sh) Bash function based on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/597414/279745). Of course, you can do it in Perl or manually, but I too lazy to issue all the commands manually whenever I want to create a new shortcut. … Anyway, if you use this function, you need to save it to file, source that file (`source path/filename.sh`).

(2) And then issue these commands:

```bsh
# Disable these 6 default shortcuts
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screenshot ''
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screenshot-clip ''
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys window-screenshot ''
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys window-screenshot-clip ''
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys area-screenshot-clip ''
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys area-screenshot ''

# Create new custom shortcuts
gshort "Screenshot of area" 'gnome-screenshot -a' "<Shift>Print"
gshort "Screenshot clip of area" 'gnome-screenshot -a -c' "<Primary><Shift>Print"
gshort "Screenshot" 'gnome-screenshot' "Print"
gshort "Screenshot clip" 'gnome-screenshot -c' "<Primary>Print"
gshort "Screenshot clip of area" 'gnome-screenshot -a -c' "<Primary><Shift>Print"
gshort "Screenshot clip of window" 'gnome-screenshot -w -c' "<Primary><Alt>Print"
```

(3) Note that the syntax of `gshort` is `gshort "Name" "command" "shortcut"`:
   - name can be anything you wish;
   - `command` can be any command you wish;
   - shortcut can be any keybord shortcut you wish.

(4) Here is the list of some control key names that you need to use in shortcut:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> : `<Primary>`;
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> : `<Alt>`;
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> : `<Shift>`;
- <kbd>Super</kbd>/<kbd>Win</kbd>: `<Super>`;

Comment: In Ubuntu 20.10 the disable value is [] not ''. e.g.:  gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screenshot []

Comment: @thanos.a, I think this depends on the GNOME Shell version instead of the Ubuntu version. I have encountered this with some other `gsettings` settings.

Answer (score 1):

### For Gnome 41.5 and later

I've tried [this extension (called "Screenshot Locations")](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1179/screenshot-locations/) as it was suggested in other answers  and I noted it is not compatible with my system (arch with gnome 41.5). So that, I looked for [another one (called "Screenshot Directory")](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4031/screenshot-directory/) and it works great!!

**Solved with**: 
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4031/screenshot-directory/

Answer (score 1):

> You don't need an Extension for such a simple task, instead do as
> following:
>
> 1- Backup your the Pictures folder
>
> 2- Delete the Pictures folder
>
> 3- Create a symbolic link to your desired screenshots directory and
> name it "Pictures"
>
> 4- Move the symbolic link to /home

Just to add on here...

You can create a symbolic link from your desired location to the place that gnome-screenshots forces. That might be ~/Pictures/Screenshots if you have Pictures defined.

If you're like me and you have XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/" in your .config/user-dirs.dirs to eliminate Pictures from Nautilus, then gnome-screenshots will put the folder in your home directory as ~/Screenshots.

After you create a link from your desired location, for example:

```
ln -s ~/.screenshots ~/Screenshots
```

then you can put a file at ~/.hidden containing

```
Screenshots
```

and it will keep it from showing in Nautilus.

Not ideal, but it keeps things looking tidy.

Comment: Very bad idea to delete any default system directory.

Comment: That's a good general rule, except there's nothing "system" about Screenshots or Pictures.

Screenshots is just the directory of one userspace app, i.e. gnome-screenshots.

And xdg-dirs is a totally optional system for defining default directories for apps. Shotwell can check xdg-dirs if there's a Pictures folder defined and if there isn't, you just define your own.

And opting in and out of specific definitions in xdg-dirs as your needs dictate is a documented feature.

It's just a shame that gnome-screenshots doesn't let you define the destination directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default save directory of screenshots in *CompizConfig Settings Manager*.
Launch it, choose **Screenshot** under the Extras category. You can then choose the default directory you wish to use.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, thanks - I do use this when wanting to grab a specific screen area. More interested about being able to set the path for gnome-screenshot.

Comment: For a specific area you can press SHIFT and PrtSc.

Comment: Strangely, this option did not work for me.

Comment: Unity is dead now.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't/wan't install dconf-editor or any other software, simply open, or create if it doesn't exist, this file, with your preferred text editor:

```
~/.bash_aliases
```

Add this line, that create a permanent alias **gss** (you can choose another alias name):

```
alias gss='gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-screenshot auto-save-directory "$(echo $PWD)"'
```

then every time you need to save several screenshots in a specific and different path simply one a terminal in that path and execute:

```
gss
```

from now on every time you press the gnome-screenshot keyboard shortcut you will be prompted or you will check for the screenshot image file in that path.

Answer (score 0):

## **Screenshot a area and save at the chosen folder**

### **By Terminal**

**Note:** *If you to cancel, instead you chosen a folder, the terminal will be close*

```
gnome-screenshot -a -f "$(zenity --file-selection --directory || kill -9 $PPID)/PrintSc $(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S').png"
```

If you don't want close it, if you to cancel your screenshot will be save in the folder "~/Pictures", with this:

```
gnome-screenshot -a -f "$(zenity --file-selection --directory || echo ~/Pictures)/PrintSc $(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S').png"
```

### **By a Shortcut**

You could create a shortcut (super+PrintSc) with this script bellow:

```
sh -c "gnome-screenshot -a -f \"$(zenity --file-selection --directory || kill -9 $PPID)/PrintSc $(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S').png\""
```

Answer (score 0):

## Full single click solution for Gnome 41.2+

Full solution, just copy to a sh file and execute the file.
This will:

1. remove the default screenshot shortcuts as we need those keyboard shortcuts for the custom shortcuts.
2. create folder /Pictures/Screenshots.
3. Set auto-save dir to that new folder.
4. Create new custom shortcuts as the auto-save dir only applies to custom screenshots.
   I have chosen shortcuts with the least number of keys and ones that make sense to me for most people. Feel free to choose other keys.

Note: Tested on Manjaro Gnome 41.2

Note: If you have other custom shortcuts, please note the key `custom-keybindings` is actually an array that you need to expand. In the below, as an example below I first create a custom shortcut for `gnome-terminal`, next I add 4 custom shortcuts for screenshots.

```
# Keyboard shortcut: Ctrl+Alt+T opens Terminal
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings "['/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/']"                  
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ name 'Terminal'         
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ command 'gnome-terminal'
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ binding '<Ctrl><Alt>T' 

# Remove Gnome default screenshot shortcuts as they will always be stored in /Pictures instead of /Pictures/Screenshots
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys area-screenshot "@as []"
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys window-screenshot "@as []"
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screenshot "@as []"
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys area-screenshot-clip "@as []"
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys window-screenshot-clip "@as []"
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screenshot-clip "@as []"

# Create Screenshots folder
mkdir $HOME/Pictures/Screenshots
gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-screenshot auto-save-directory "file:///home/${USER}/Pictures/Screenshots/"

# Create custom screenshot shortcuts, only custom shortcuts ARE stored to the auto-save-directory
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings "['/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom2/', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom3/', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom4/', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom5/']"     
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/ name 'Area screenshot to custom folder'
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/ command 'gnome-screenshot -a'
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/ binding 'Print'
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom2/ name 'Area screenshot to clipboard'
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom2/ command 'gnome-screenshot -a -c'
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom2/ binding '<Shift>Print'
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom3/ name 'Window screenshot to custom folder'
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom3/ command 'gnome-screenshot -w -p'
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom3/ binding '<Alt>Print'
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom4/ name 'window screenshot to clipboard'
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom4/ command 'gnome-screenshot -w -c'
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom4/ binding '<Primary>Print'
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom5/ name 'Interactive screenshot to cust folder'
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom5/ command 'gnome-screenshot -i -p'
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom5/ binding '<Primary><Shift>Print'
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an Extension for such a simple task, instead do as following:

1- Backup your the `Pictures` folder

2- Delete the `Pictures` folder

3- Create a symbolic link to your desired screenshots directory and name it "Pictures"

4- Move the symbolic link to /home

Answer (score 0):

Since the gsettings solution no longer works, and the Gnome Extensions site claims the "Screenshot Locations" extension is incompatible with my system (Ubuntu 22.04), I gave up on elegance and elected to just symlink both `~/Pictures/Screenshots` and `~/Videos/Screencasts` to the folder that I prefer those files end up in - in my case, `~/Downloads`, which I use as my general inbox.

Just tested both and it works.  Only downside is having to see those symlinks in the Pictures and Videos folders.

Answer (score -2):

On Elementary OS Juno which is based on Ubuntu 18.04, even after you remove all the screenshots tools like gnome-screenshot or screenshot-tool, you can still use `PrtSc` or `Shift+PrtSC` to take a screenshot. So when the `PrtSc`, actually a different screenshot tool is called and by default the picture is saved to `XDG_PICTURES_DIR`. You can modify this environment variable `XDG_PICTURES_DIR` in `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`,

```
# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run.
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
# 
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
...
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures/screenshots"
```

So maybe on Ubuntu GNOME 17.04, it's also the case. Then you can also use the above method to change the location of saved screenshot.

Comment: Changing `XDG_PICTURES_DIR` to `$HOME/Pictures/screenshots` defeats the goal for all intents and purposes really. The idea was to *not* use the *default pictures folder* (which is dictated by `XDG_PICTURES_DIR`) for saving screenshots, instead to use a different dedicated folder. Your answer suggests marking the dedicated screenshots folder itself as the default pictures folder. So this screenshots folder would be used as the default pictures folder for *all* purposes after making this change.

Answer (score -3):

For those who can't install dconf-editor and are terminal users, I would suggest to edit the .bashrc file in your home directory. Put anywhere in the file the line "mv ~/Pictures/Screenshot* ---put-here-desired-path---". The only problem with this method is that, in case you have a file starting with the string "Screenshot", it will be moved to the desired path you've put above.

Comment: What a dreadful idea.