# Can not change default save directory for gnome-screenshot

Tags: 12.04

I just fresh installed Ubuntu 12.04 but using my old 11.10 `/home` partition as the `/home` point for the 12.04. 
(**update**: in other words, the 12.04 applications should most likely use my old 11.10 application configurations. actually they are.)

Weird thing is, I can not seemed to change the default saved directory for `gnome-screenshot`. I tried to change the saved location from `~/Pictures` to `~/Pictures/Screenshots` at the first screenshot. But in the second screenshot, the saved directory is still `~/Picture`.

Here is the `gconf.xml`:

```
petra@petra-laptop:~$ cat .gconf/apps/gnome-screenshot/%gconf.xml 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gconf>
    <entry name="last_save_directory" mtime="1335771751" type="string">
        <stringvalue>file:///home/petra/Pictures/Screenshots</stringvalue>
    </entry>
    <entry name="border_effect" mtime="1335771746" type="string">
        <stringvalue>none</stringvalue>
    </entry>
    <entry name="delay" mtime="1335771746" type="int" value="0"/>
    <entry name="include_pointer" mtime="1335771746" type="bool" value="false"/>
    <entry name="include_border" mtime="1335771746" type="bool" value="true"/>
</gconf>
```

The screenshot should use the `last_save_directory`, right? 
(**update**: the unix timestamp shows `1335771751` which means `Mon 30 Apr 2012 02:42:31 PM WIT GMT+7` few hours after I installed the 12.04, so this should means the `gnome-screenshot` successfully wrote the `gconf.xml` file)

And I also tried changing it from the **CompizConfig Setting Manager**, but also gives no luck.

Is there any other way to do it? (or should I report it to the Launchpad? I've never done it before, though)

**update**: Here's the fstab

```
petra@petra-laptop:~$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=b7b72b03-f7e6-4665-a4cd-fa0df5b2a0cf /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=6c4d7a04-1e5f-4514-98a9-3e37867b34e8 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=5ecd35ad-d3bf-482c-bdac-dc3eae31ee8e none            swap    sw              0       0
```

**update**:

I just tried capturing few screenshot and saved it to other directories instead of `~/Pictures/Screenshots`. Apparently the `gconf.xml` wasn't updated after the latest screenshots.

Comment: Are you using Unity or Gnome-Shell?

Comment: I am using Unity

Comment: hmmm ... cannot reproduce this.  Maybe your fstab is wrong?  Can you add the contents of /etc/fstab to your question.

Comment: okay, i pasted the fstab. what does it have to do with the `gnome-screenshot`?

Comment: ... was double checking that you didnt have some sort of strange mounting issue since you were using your old /home.  All looks ok.  In that case - no idea why you are seeing this and I'm not :(

Comment: I just tried capturing few screenshot and saved it to other directories instead of `~/Pictures/Screenshots`. Apparently the `gconf.xml` wasn't updated after the latest screenshots. Shouldn't it be the place to store the configuration for `gnome-screenshot`?

Comment: it appears to be correct - its correctly updated on my machine.

Comment: Mine is a "clean" install of 12.04 with a new (and just the one /home) and I see something similar. Pressing `printscreen` to take a screen shot always suggests `~/home/Pictures` as the default save location no matter how many times I select `~/home/Desktop`. Interestingly, if I run `gnome-screenshot -i` from a terminal (to use the time delay), it suggests saving to `~/home/Desktop`!

Comment: @vasa1: yeah, i just tried after reading your comment. i run the `gnome-screenshot -i`, it suggested saving to `~/Pictures/Screenshots`, just like what I needed.

Comment: The mystery remains. In my case, this `gconf.xml` seems to reflect the terminal command with the `-i` switch. I feel that is so because of the time delay is mentioned in that file and that `gconf.xml` file has `Desktop` as destination. I'm wondering whether there are different settings for `gnome-screenshot` when launched by pressing `printscreen` (which offers `Pictures` as the destination) versus being run from the terminal (which offers `Desktop`.).

Comment: Same problem here. Seems to be a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screenshot/+bug/977228

Comment: possible duplicate of [Default save directory for gnome-screenshot?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/114429/default-save-directory-for-gnome-screenshot)