# Change default 'Print Screen' save folder

Tags: 12.04, screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Default save directory for gnome-screenshot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114429/default-save-directory-for-gnome-screenshot)

The `Print Screen` window that appears when pressing the `ImprPant` button (at least, that's what it's called in my keyboard) has the "Save Folder" set to `/home/myusername/` by default. I'd like to change that folder so that `/home/myusername/Downloads/`is the default, but there are no options available that I can see.

How can I do this?

Comment: Yes, it definitely is.

Comment: It definitely is what? A question? We know that. How about an answer? When I searched for this in Google this is where it led me.  Ah, yes.  An answer below.  Google FTW!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Install `dconf-editor`:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Open it up and head to *org* --> *gnome* --> *gnome-screenshot*. Under *auto-save-directory* set the URI to your default directory:

```
file:///path/to/directory
```

Comment: O.O this can't be the easiest way to achieve something as simple as changing the default save folder of an app, can it??

Comment: There is a way to change the dconf setting from the command line directly. I don't know how, though. But yes, it's a lot of effort to change one simple setting. That's how linux is sometimes :/

Comment: haha using the command line is even worst! I personally don't have a problem with it, but I thought Ubuntu was supposed to be the easy Linux OS option...

Comment: Oh, well, linux is still linux and the powerful command line one of its trademarks. You'll get used to it. If you are unhappy with the screenshot tool in general, you might want to check out some of the (very good) alternatives: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6558/what-screenshot-tools-are-available

Comment: I am already used to the command line, I use it all the time but that is definitely a very **poor** solution for a newcomer.
Funny that you mention the alternatives because I installed `Shutter` long ago but haven't found an option to make it the default app yet when pressing the `ImprPant` key!

Comment: @Gabriel You can remove the "print screen" shortcut to "take screenshot" in  keyboard settings (just keyboard in unity app view)...and add a custom shortcut for shutter if you want...

Comment: Works for me in August 2017 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.  My Google search led me directly to this answer.  Thank you.