# 17.10 printscreen snipping tool

Tags: 17.10, print-screen

In previous versions (with unity) I could do <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd> and copy the partial screenshot into clipboard without saving to file first.

Is there a way to enable a similar functionality in 17.10?

Also, can I make it ask for saving location instead of saving always into `~/pictures`?

Comment: Its still working for me in 17.10. shift+prtsrc

Comment: You can try **shutter**

Comment: It works for me too `Ctrl+Alt+Prtscr`. (shift+prt just saves as a file for me)

Answer (score 6):

You can check it out from Settings:

**Device > keyboard > keyboard shortcuts > screenshots**

You can copy it to clipboard without saving using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd>

[image: Screenshot shortcuts from settings]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Thanks - I found it, by default it is mapped to 'Ctrl+Alt+Print'

Answer (score 5):

In the Gnome-* environment that 17.10 has, it looks like (shift+printscrn) or just (printscrn) automatically saves in the default folder(Pictures or so) without giving an option to just copy to clipboard(and discard the file without saving it) and/or save it in whatever location needed. This along with so many other things have made life uneasy for the ones comfortable with the Unity-ish features which provided the above.

I wanted this as well that was with the good old Unity. Now, after having upgraded to 17.10, the whole look and feel Gnome-change, and what not, it became a major inconvenience and felt a lot like out of the place. So, I really wanted to get the 17.04 Unity look and feel back along with all the Unity panel operations, etc, so I removed Gnome-* specific stuff, installed Unity - desktop, session, greeter, lightdm, indicator-sound, unity-control-center, reinstalled graphics drivers(Nvidia in my case), with couple of attempts(reboot, etc), I got everything back like the old 17.04 had including the screenshot/clipboard copying, etc.

Also, I didn't want the big central sound level indicator that appears at the bottom of the screen masking the screen whenever I increased/decreased/muted volume either using the multimedia keys or using the mouse scroll wheel over the top bar sound icon. Tried so many things and looked around in the internet to get rid of it. But none, helped. Also, Gnome-based environment looked very sluggish when compared to that of Unity. Going back to Unity fixed this as it was in 17.04.

Kudos to the oldie, Unity as long as it works and lasts with 17.10 Ubuntu and future versions!

Comment: Agreed. I knew gnome was garbage right around 2012 when they made gnome 3, the ugliest gnome yet. It was just downhill from there. And since Debian had no choice but to continue supporting gnome, it got more and more traction. The big reason gnome took over in Ubuntu was thanks to the massive failure of wayland and mir to deliver. They have great potential, but they seem to compete with each other and both lost the fight to be the default Ubuntu display manager.

Comment: Gnome-* environment is the crappiest desktop I have used and is full of junk. Gnome-* environment looks somewhat modern with dock, etc. But, eventually, I got fed up with its crappy lack of features like switching to windows using mouse scroll wheel over the app icons on the launcher, etc that Unity has by default, etc. So, I just got rid of the useless Gnome-* as fast as I could for the good.

Answer (score 3):

Try `Ctrl+Shift+Prtscr`, it should copy a selected area to clipboard and will not save it to file.

The other part of your problem may get solved from here :- https://askubuntu.com/a/191539/611441

Comment: I don't want it to save to a specific folder, but ask for any screenshot, just like in 17.04

Comment: I know its not exactly what you want but adding `gnome-screenshot -ai` to a keyboard shortcut gives you control over where to store the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Ubuntu's official help](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/screen-shot-record.html), what you are looking for is gone now.

(Which, btw., I find sad as well but things change.)

Answer (score -1):

Try Spectacle   It works....

> Spectacle Spectacle is a simple application for capturing desktop
>   screenshots. It can capture images of the entire desktop, a single
>   monitor, the currently active window, the window currently under the
>   mouse, or a rectangular region of the screen. The images can then be
>   printed, sent to other applications for manipulation, or quickly be
>   saved as-is.

See [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXYg3.png)