# How to change the save directory for taking a screenshot for Ubuntu 17.10 Gnome?

Tags: 17.10, gnome-screenshot

If I press `Print Screen` then click and drag an area, it saves the screenshot to /home/james/pictures. How do I change the default save directory?

It seems like I can't under keyboard shortcuts:

[image]

I guess that you'd have to create a custom shortcut, although I'm not sure what command you'd use.

I'll try [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191533/change-default-print-screen-save-folder/191539#191539).

Unfortunately it didn't work after I tried a few options:

[image]

[image]

Current values after saving:

[image]

[image]

Comment: **NOTE:** The command to capture an area instead of the whole screen is `gnome-screenshot -a`.

Answer (score 3):

I saw this from [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/51erc1/how_to_change_the_default_gnome_screenshot_folder/) and steps were:

1. Change the default location using `gsettings`:

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-screenshot auto-save-directory 'file:///home/cialu/Downloads'
   ```
2. Modify the default shotcut behaviour as per a [bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=699642):

   - create a shortcut in `Settings > Keyboard`, pressing the `+` button there. Assign a name (e.g. "New screenshot") and the command to gnome-screenshot.
   - click in the "Disabled" label in the new shortcut and press the "Print Screen" key from you PC. Confirm the dialog that will ask you if you want to reassign the key to this new shortcut.

Note: Not tested by me.

Source:

https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/51erc1/how_to_change_the_default_gnome_screenshot_folder/

Comment: It works George, I have tested it in both Zesty and Artful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/961094/change-the-location-of-saved-screenshot-when-screenshot-taken-by-printscreen-but

Comment: @pomsky done so!

Comment: For some reason using `gsettings` didn't work:

`james@james-Streacom:~$ gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-screenshot auto-save-directory \`file:///media/james/Seagate Expansion Drive/Downloads/Screenshots\``.

It just gave me a `>` prompt. But changing the location via the Dconf editor as per @pomsky's answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/961149/724441) worked along with disabling the default shortcut and replacing that same shortcut with a `gnome-screenshot` command (or with one of it's options like `-w` or `-a`).