# How to add Print Screen Functionality?

Tags: 12.04, cinnamon, ubuntu-minimal

I just started with ubuntu minimal and LAMP stack.. Cinnamon is the GUI

Now what i want is the print-screen functionality,
so that when i hit the <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> the screenshot must take place being saved as an image (jpe/jpeg) file somewhere.

Comment: You should have a keyboard shortcuts settings menu in Cinnamon. For example in Unity under All Settings->Keyboard->Shortcuts there is a Screenshots option and my system has this assigned to the Print key. Look for something similar in Cinnamon.

Comment: The keyboard shortcut setting is already there.. however not working for me ! THE SYSTEM IS A MINIMAL INSTALL !

Comment: Can you take a screenshot by running the screenshot application? Open a terminal and type `gnome-screenshot` Perhaps you need to `sudo apt-get install gnome-screenshot`

Comment: i did apt-get and when i ran gnome-screenshot... my screen flashed and the next comment is what the terminal said..  where to find the screeshot ??

Comment: THE RESPONCE OF TERMINAL** (gnome-screenshot:4344): WARNING **: Unable to use GNOME Shell's builtin screenshot interface, resorting to fallback X11. Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.Shell was not provided by any .service files

Comment: Check inside your pictures folder. Is there a screenshot there?

Comment: Nowhere to be found.. infact there isnt any pictures folder aswell...  i managed to get the a working GUI with  gnome-screenshot -i command which actually worked and asked me to save the snapshot to my prefered location.... however with the shortcut commands the screen merly blinks and the snapshot is to be found nowher

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6791/discussion-between-colin-matheson-and-z9it)

Comment: try restarting the cinnamon and removing the cache then reconfiguring the shortcuts !

Comment: Continuing from our chat it looks like a similar issue on this post. Try setting the default save directory using the method described in the link http://askubuntu.com/questions/114429/default-save-directory-for-gnome-screenshot

Comment: thanks for pointing me to the post. however gnome-screenshot is working perfectly.. its just that the kbd shortcuts wont save it anywhere but merely flash the screen once !

Comment: try the command $gnome-screenshot -i

Answer (score 0):

`gnome-screenshot` should do what you want, but depends on a number of other packages. You may find that installing it with aptitude is more robust at resolving [these dependencies](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/gnome/gnome-screenshot)