# Installing gnome screenshot

Tags: screenshot

I followed this advice [Default save directory for gnome-screenshot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114429/default-save-directory-for-gnome-screenshot) and installed it as the top answer suggested.

But the "screenshot" does not appear (see image). https://www.dropbox.com/s/ud2p8bv8v3z0w9m/snapshot7.png?dl=0

And here is my installation https://www.dropbox.com/s/c0gnxuead911dzc/snapshot8.png?dl=0

---

Edit, myabe this should be a different quesiton now, but I looked in the preferences for Ksnapshot and googled for it but could find no way to do it.

What I want to achieve is:
each time I press PrtSc or ctrl+prsc I save a file named

screenshot_todaysdate

to

/Dropbox/folder

and then the URL is pasted to my clipboard.

Comment: Why are you using gnome-screen shot in a KDE desktop ?

Comment: I did not know Ksnapshot "should" be used and gnome screenshot not; I thought that you could prefer one or the other. My bad.

Comment: @markkirby I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

For KDE use KSnapshot, it should be installed, if not

```
sudo apt-get install ksnapshot
```

If you must use this I think you will need all the libs required for a gnome environment.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

This should help