# Changing screenshot directory in Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: screenshot, gnome-screenshot

I am trying to change the default folder where the screenshots are saved.  Currently, they are saved in `/home/USERNAME/Pictures` while I would like for this to be something like `/home/USERNAME/OTHER_FOLDER`.  I have already tried

- `Tweaks` (could not find the spot)
- `dconf-editor` then `org/gnome/gnome-screenshot/auto-save-directory`
- Which is the same as from terminal: `gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-screenshot auto-save-directory '/home/USERNAME/OTHER_FOLDER'`
- Installing the [Screenshot location extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1179/screenshot-locations/) (did not even create the Extensions tab as it is supposed to)

All these as shown in multiple places including [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114429/how-can-i-specify-the-default-save-directory-for-gnome-screenshot) which has multiple answers for all sorts of versions.  One *For 18.04 and later* includes comments saying it worked up to 20.04.  Unfortunately, this is not working for me in 21.10.

I would prefer not to install [KDE's KSnapshot as suggested here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/515384/installing-gnome-screenshot).

It is getting a bit frustrating so any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution and it was within the set I had put above.  However, it has a little twist that was missing from [the answer provided here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114429/how-can-i-specify-the-default-save-directory-for-gnome-screenshot).

It is possible to use the [Screenshot location extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1179/screenshot-locations/) but instead of looking for the `Extensions` tab within `Tweaks`, just go directly to the [Gnome Installed Extensions page](https://extensions.gnome.org/local/) and then click on the configuration button for the Screenshot location extension and select the folder you want and voilà.

Here is a screenshot of the configuration window: [image: screenshot of configuration window]

Comment: Note: for the sake of completeness, I added this as one of the answers to: https://askubuntu.com/questions/114429/how-can-i-specify-the-default-save-directory-for-gnome-screenshot so people can find it in either spot.

Answer (score 4):

if using [Screenshot Tool](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1112/screenshot-tool/) from the drop down menu in the Taskbar select `Settings` then the `Storage` tab.

The `Save Location` can be changed there.

[image]

Comment: Thank you... for the tip.  This replaces the tool to take the screenshots, it does not, however, address the issue with the default path with the default tool.  It is a workaround (and a nice one at that since it seems to have a number of additional options).  It seems as though I will have to do a bit more work to get this to work as setting the key bindings to replace the default ones is giving me some grief but I am sure I will get this to work.  Once/if I manage to make it work I will post it here.