# Set default folder for screenshots

Tags: directory, default, screenshot

I take screenshots very often. I have a dedicated folder for screenshots, but I have to select it each time I take a snapshot with Ubuntu's default screenshots tool. How can I set the default folder to save them to?

[image]

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/114429/default-save-directory-for-gnome-screenshot