# Define default directory for keyboard-trigered screenshots in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, screenshot, gnome-screenshot, print-screen

**Background**
I want my screenshots to be saved in my `~/pictures/screenshots` directory. I have then followed instructions of the selected answer of [Default save directory for gnome-screenshot?](https://askubuntu.com/a/134469/498358) — i.e., I've run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-screenshot auto-save-directory "file:///home/$USER/pictures/screenshots"
```

**Problem**
When I take a screenshot using the <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> key of my keyboard, the `.png` file is still saved under `~/pictures`. (I've checked with `dconf` GUI, and the setting *is* `file:///home/$USER/pictures/screenshots`.

In the [comments of the aforementioned question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114429/default-save-directory-for-gnome-screenshot#comment1152990_134469), it is said:

> Be aware that Gnome 3.8 doesn't use gnome-screenshot when using keyboard commands.

**Question**
How to make screenshots made using keyboard commands be saved in my customized `~/pictures/screenshots` folder?