# Update the default location for screenshot in Ubuntu 18.04+?

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, gnome-screenshot

How do you update the default location for Screenshots in Ubuntu 18.04+?

Note: There is a similar question @ [Default save directory for gnome-screenshot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114429/default-save-directory-for-gnome-screenshot/1075441?noredirect=1#comment2118380_1075441). But the accepted answers are not so clear, so a separate question for easier accessibility.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note: I have tested this in Ubuntu 18.04 but this works in Ubuntu 20.04 as well.

First disable the default screenshot shortcut from settings:

[image: Disable default screenshot shortcut]

Create a custom keyboard shortcut in the settings:

Name it gnome-screenshot, put the command as gnome-screenshot as well

Shortcut value : enter the key [Print Screen]

Create a custom shortcut:

[image: Create a custom shortcut]

Now enter into dconf-editor (Install it if you do not have it yet).
Go to: org -> gnome -> gnome-screenshot -> auto-save-directory: Change the auto save directory's custom value to the one you want.

Enter the custom path:

[image: Enter the custom path]

Comment: I am trying to do this on Ubuntu 20.04 and I can't figure out how to "create a custom keyboard shortcut in settings". I have managed to disable the default keyboard shortcut, but that's it. How does one do this on 20.04?

Comment: Go to Keyboard Shortcuts, click on the + button at the bottom and follow the steps shown in the answer. Also, don't forget to install dconf-editor. If you still have troubles, ping me.

Comment: sorry, I was having trouble finding the + button. I re-read https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html.en a few times and now I get it. AND it worked! Thanks for your prompt reply and useful fix! +1

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Can test it works perfectly with Ubuntu 20.04. Thank you!